# (java) incompatible types?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error in compilation:

> 'incompatible types - found unit but expected unit'

Why is this?
This is when returning from a method, I can even parse the returning data into 'unit' and it works fine, why is this error occurring?
Does the fact that I am using an iterator within a collection I have made have anything to do with it? I haven't left the iterator type E as I specifically want this collection for one type of object.

```
private class unitHashIterator<unit> implements Iterator<unit> {
  private unitHash hash;
  private int nextIndex;
  private unitHashIterator(unitHash u) {
    hash = u; nextIndex = 0;
  }
  public unit next() {
    if(!hasNext())
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return hash.data[nextIndex++]; << HERE OCCURS THE ERROR
  }
}
```

This class is contained within a collection.

> 'incompatible types - found unit but expected unit'

Comment: This is going to be impossible to answer without seeing the actual error message (or **messages**) and the actual source code highlighting the line where the error occurred.

Comment: private class unitHashIterator<unit> implements Iterator<unit>
    {
        private unitHash hash;
        private int nextIndex;
        
        private unitHashIterator(unitHash u)
        {
            hash = u;
            nextIndex = 0;
        }
        
        ...
        
        public unit next()
        {
            if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
            return hash.data[nextIndex++]; << HERE OCCURS THE ERROR
        }
        
       ...
    }
This class is contained within a collection.
'incompatible types - found unit but expected unit'

Comment: `hash.data[nextIndex++]` returns what exactly?  What is `hash.data`?

Comment: BTW, class names should start with capital letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the definition of unitHash, it can't possibly be guaranteed contain elements of type unit, because unitHash isn't parameterized over types but unitHashIterator is. I suspect you either meant to write `class unitHashIterator` rather than `class unitHashIterator<unit>`, or  `private unitHash<unit> hash;` rather than `private unitHash<unit> hash;`.

The error message you're getting is probably because the compiler expects to return something of the same type as the type variable `unit`, but `hash` returns something of some concrete type (not type variable) that happens to also be named `unit`.

Comment: The change in the class header fixed it. Thanks!